# Combine two query as single laravel

Tags: mysql, laravel

I have two queries:

**Query 1**

```
$usersdetails = DB::table('users as a')
    ->join('Appraiser_commands as b', 'a.id', '=', 'b.user_id')
    ->select('a.id as userid', 'b.cycle_id as cycleid', 'a.name as uname', 'b.mode as mode')
    ->where('a.head_id', '=', $id)
    ->where('b.mode', '=', 'proceed')
    ->get()->toArray();
```

**Query 2**

```
$usersdetailsApp = DB::table('users as a')
    ->join('Appraiser_commands as b', 'a.id', '=', 'b.user_id')
    ->select('a.id as userid', 'b.cycle_id as cycleid', 'a.name as uname', 'b.mode as mode')
    ->where('b.mode', '=', 'Approved')
    ->get()->toArray();
```

both single query working well..
I am trying to combine there two queries as single query so I've tried

```
$usersdetails = DB::table('users as a')
    ->join('Appraiser_commands as b', 'a.id', '=', 'b.user_id')
    ->select('a.id as userid', 'b.cycle_id as cycleid', 'a.name as uname', 'b.mode as mode')
    ->where('a.head_id', '=', $id)
    ->where('b.mode', '=', 'proceed')
    ->orWhere('b.mode', '=', 'Approved')
    ->get()->toArray();
```

But this is not working. I am new in laravel, please help.

Comment: what error it shows?

Comment: @LeenaPatel no error but nothing displays..if its single query i will get answer

Comment: can you print the query generated by the eloquent and use that query in your database so that will show if there is any error. explained here https://blog.phakeapps.com/2015/03/12/get-the-last-query-executed-in-laravel/

Comment: use `where group`

Answer (score 2):

try this:

```
$usersdetails = DB::table('users as a')
    ->join('Appraiser_commands as b', 'a.id', '=', 'b.user_id')
    ->select('a.id as userid', 'b.cycle_id as cycleid', 'a.name as uname', 'b.mode as mode')
    ->where(function ($query) use ($id) {
        $query->where('a.head_id', $id)->orWhereIn('b.mode',
            ['proceed', 'Approved']);
    })
    ->get()->toArray();
```

Answer (score 1):

try this one

```
$usersdetails = DB::table('users as a')
    ->join('Appraiser_commands as b', 'a.id', '=', 'b.user_id')
    ->select('a.id as userid', 'b.cycle_id as cycleid', 'a.name as uname','b.mode as mode')
    ->where('a.head_id', '=', $id)
    ->where(function($query){
         $query->where('b.mode', '=', 'proceed');
         $query->orwhere('b.mode', '=', 'Approved');
     })
    ->get()->toArray();
```

using `where group` you can create `and` `or` query group for better result group wise

Answer (score 1):

Looking at your queries, you don't have `->where('a.head_id', '=', $id)` in Query 2.

Remove that condition and add the `head_id` to the select so that you can manually check if the head_id matches afterwards:

```
$usersdetails = DB::table('users as a')
    ->join('Appraiser_commands as b', 'a.id', '=', 'b.user_id')
    ->select('a.id as userid', 'b.cycle_id as cycleid', 'a.name as uname', 'b.mode as mode', 'a.head_id as headid')
    ->where('b.mode', 'proceed')
    ->orWhere('b.mode', 'Approved')
    ->get()->toArray();
```